# Open multiple .vbs one by one

Tags: vbscript

i want .vbs script, to open multiple large files .vbs [i want to Open .vbs one by one] that do not make me, lag in PC.

0001.vbs, 0002.vbs, 0003.vbs, 0004.vbs 
is can be different names like: 
Anna.vbs, Diana.vbs, Antony.vbs, Andy.vbs

Example:

```
run C:\0001.vbs
MsgBox "0001.vbs IS END"

Next Open run C:\0002.vbs
MsgBox  YES  NO
MsgBox "0002.vbs IS END"

Next Open run C:\0003.vbs
MsgBox  YES  NO
MsgBox "0003.vbs IS END"

Next Open run C:\0004.vbs
MsgBox  YES  NO
MsgBox "0004.vbs IS END"
```

Thank you for you help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To **not** make you wait for each sub process/.vbs before you start the next, **don't** use the 3rd/wait/true parameter to the .Run method:

a.vbs

```
Option Explicit
Dim oWSH : Set oWSH = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim v
For v = 0 To 1
    oWSH.Run "cscript.exe " & v & ".vbs", 0, False
Next
MsgBox WScript.ScriptName & " done. " & Now()
```

0.vbs, 1.vbs

```
Option Explicit
Randomize
WScript.Sleep Rnd() * 1000
MsgBox WScript.ScriptName & " done. " & Now()
```

Evidence:

[image: How it looks]

As you can see, a.vbs is finished first and 0.vbs and 1.vbs terminate in random/not in call order.

Answer (score 2):

```
Set Shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

For i = 1 To 4

    strFile = Right("0000" & i, 4) & ".vbs"

    If MsgBox("Would you like to run " & strFile & "?", vbYesNo Or vbQuestion) = vbYes Then
        Shell.Run "c:\" & strFile, 1, True
        MsgBox strFile & " IS END"
    End If

Next
```

Just make sure you pass `True` as the last parameter to `Shell.Run` so that this script waits until the others are done before reporting that they've ended.

**Edit:** To answer your comment about using names, you can loop through an array created on-the-fly.

```
For Each strName In Array("Anna", "Diana", "Antony", "Andy")

Next
```

Comment: Thank you. I hope to be good. may have. different names [0001.vbs, 0002.vbs, 0003.vbs, 0004.vbs ] was for Example:

Comment: 0001.vbs, 0002.vbs, 0003.vbs, 0004.vbs is can be different names like: Anna.vbs, Diana.vbs, Antony.vbs, Andy.vbs

Comment: For numbers very good and one for names Anna.vbs, Diana.vbs, Antony.vbs, Andy.vbs

Comment: I've added a edit to my answer showing how you can loop through a list of names. You should be able to combine what I showed originally with this to accomplish what you need.

Answer (score 0):

We have
0001.vbs, 0002.vbs, 0003.vbs, 0004.vbs

Assuming that you have this script file with the after mentioned files in the same directory.

If not, just modify the full path of your vbs files you want to run.

Instead of

```
WshShell.Run ".\0001.vbs"
```

You use for example:

```
WshShell.Run "c:\indel\0001.vbs"
```

This is the script:

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
      WshShell.Run ".\0001.vbs"
      WshShell.Run ".\0002.vbs"
      WshShell.Run ".\0003.vbs"
      WshShell.Run ".\0004.vbs"
```

Answer (score -2):

What you need to do is make this code

```
do
msgbox("haha you cant close this")
CreateObject ("WScript.Shell").Run(".\Duplicate.vbs")
loop
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).